# change background color for datagrid cell datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background

I want to change the cells (not the row) background color when the content is changed depending on a different cells date value.

For example, if `DateTime.Today = > date`, this is what I tried but I can't get it further.
 In this example, I want to compare the selected date to the same row column[8]:

```
private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)sender;
   DataRow dtr = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(MyDataGrid.SelectedValue)).Row;
   DateTime dt = new DateTime();
   dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dtr[8].ToString());


   if (dp.SelectedDate > dt)
   {
       //datagridcell.background = Brushes.Red;              

   }
}
```

Comment: Did you know that your title says `Foreground` when your question says `Background`?

Comment: Thanx for editing it but I still Need an Answer